# Search for a string in a tuple inside a Python list

Tags: python, list

I have a `list` in Python,

```
a=[("title","artiste"),
   ("titl","artste"),
   ("ttle","titl")]
```

I want to create a second list; the second list should not include the search term.

How to search whether `"titl"` is in the first string of the tuples (just the first string, not the second string) of the three tuples or not?

Comment: In which language? Looks like Python.

Comment: Is this python, JS or what? also please add some code so we know what you have done so far

Comment: yeah python... I thought this web is just for python, sorry xD

Answer (score 2):

Use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) and a *[generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions)* to determine whether the first (`[0]`) element of *any* of the [*tuples*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) (*`t`*) [`in`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#in) *`list`*  *`a`* equal `'titl'`:

```
>>> any((t[0] == 'titl' for t in a))
True
```

Comment: thx for your fast response dude :3
I never thought about it xD

Comment: Minor: the inner set of parentheses is unnecessary here.

Comment: @DSM: True. I figured that [Explicit is better than implicit.](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) :-)

Comment: @user3528188: Happy to help ☺︎ ︎︎ Note that this is a *list* of ***tuples***, not a *list* of *lists*.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: what is it that you're being explicit about?  There's no ambiguity here.

Comment: @DSM: You're right, it seems that there is no ambiguity and  `any(t[0] == 'titl' for t in a)` is implicitly a [generator expression](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) and will not be interpreted as a list comprehension. Because [`join()` performs better with list comprehesions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/78845), I've got into the habit of spelling out what I want.